# Add menu item in hook form submit

Tags: routes, navigation, forms

I have an entity, when i submit this entity i want to add the new entity created in a menu as a link. But in this menu i have a tree links so i don't know how to put my link in a specific tree. I saw the "mlid" and the "plid", i think "mlid" is the id of the menu and the "plid" is the id of the mother link.

So if I want to add a new item, what do I need to do? Do I get the ID of the parent link? 
Do I need to use `menu_link_save()`? How do I construct my new link?

This is the code I am using.

```
$menu_intervenant_loaded = menu_load_links('menu-intervenant-project'. $idProject);

foreach ($menu_intervenant_loaded as $menu_item) {
  $menutitle = str_replace(" ","+", $menu_item['link_title']);
  $mlid = $menu_item['mlid'];
  $link = menu_link_load($mlid);
  $haschildren = $menu_item['has_children'];
  if ($menutitle == "Entreprises") {
    //The parent link: here is where I need to create my link.
    $item = array(
        'title' => 'Montitre',
        'access' => TRUE,
        'link_path' => 'encore un test',
        'link_title' => 'Mon titre qui fonctionne pas',
        'plid' => $mlid,
        'customized' => 1,
        'external' => 1,
    );

    menu_link_save($item);
  }
}
```

EDIT : With this code the link appear when i debug my menu before submit, but doesn't appear in my administration and front-end where the menu is placed..

Answer (score 0):

Value of `plid` is the menu link id of the item you want your new item to be a child of (=**parent id**).

To create your link, simply use something like:

```
$item = array(
  'link_path' => 'node/' . $node->nid,
  'link_title' => $node->title,
  'plid' => 426,
);
menu_link_save($item);
```

Comment: Thanks i tried that but the link isn't added to my menu, but when i debug the menu i can see the link added is the link list of this menu. Why he isn't appear in my administration of this menu ?

Comment: Sorry @Remi I don't understand very well what happens. The link doesn't appear neither in your menu (front-end), nor in the admin (admin->structure->menu) but you see it where??

Comment: Ok sorry for my english. The link appear when i debug (kpr($link);) my menu, i can see all my links of this menu. But in my "admin->structure->menu" and my "front-end where the menu is placed" the link created doesn't appear.

Comment: Could you try to add a line in $item array: 'customized' => 1, ?

Comment: I saved my link with that array: $item = array('link_path' => 'blabla','link_title' => 'Lot 1','title' => 'Lot 1','plid' => $mlid,'customized' => 1); And nothing appear. The link is saved because i can see him if i debug the menu but won't appear in my administration and front-end... So i don't know why.

Comment: 'hidden' => 0, maybe? ;-) Seriously, I don't know why it doesn't work either... :-(

Comment: Nope, hidden is defined automaticaly when i create my link.. I updated my post with the code... ty for your try.